# How do I get vanilla Markdown style relative links to work with vanilla Jekyll and Github pages?

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages, github-flavored-markdown

**tl;dr** I want Markdown, relative links, Jekyll, and Github pages to play well together.

I would like to be able to view a file that contains working *vanilla Markdown style relative links* (i.e. `[a relative link](other_file.md)`) on Github and on Github pages using Jekyll.

So far this works with viewing said file on Github [since Github added support for relative links](https://github.com/blog/1395-relative-links-in-markup-files).

However this doesn't work out of the box in Jekyll because it expects `{{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.url }}`.

Is there some preprocessor or other method I could use to get vanilla Markdown style relative links working in Jekyll without using any 'unsafe' plugins?

Answer (score 2):

### Markdown, relative links, Jekyll, and Github pages are playing well together

#### Markdown

Default Markdown parser for Jekyll is [Kramdown](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/). It allows you to write markdown in file (page.md or page.markdown) and in variables.

When you have some markdown in a variable, you can parse it with {{ variable | markdownify }}

#### Markdown links

Your example link (`[a relative link](other_file.md)`) will render a perfect relative link from you page to the other_file.md sibling page.

You are free to use this syntax.

#### `{{ site.baseurl }}` and `{{ post.url }}` variables

Those variables are not mandatory in Jekyll.

`{{ post.url }}` is often found in for loops and result in links like `[{{ post.title }}]({{ post.url }})` and this is only automation. And you're not obliged to use automation.

`{{ site.baseurl }}` (which is different from `{{ site.url }}`) is a very useful variable to build links relative to site root.

A link like `[a relative link](/other_file.md)` will only work if your site is at the root of a domain, because it converted like `/other_file.html`.
If you site is hosted at `domain.tld.blog`, this link will miss is target.

If you set `baseurl: /blog` in your `_config.yml` file.
Adding `[a relative link]({{ site.baseurl }}/other_file.md)` will give you the perfect relative link to root : `/blog/other_file.html`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It looks like I'm close but not quite there. I believe I have my _config.yml configured correctly but I still can't get relative links to work in this test post: http://stevemoser.org/starter/blog/2014/11/19/this-is-a-test/

Comment: Hmm so it appears that I can use `[a relative link](other_file.md)` with a project page and a custom domain?

Answer (score -1):

I am using Cory Gross [docsync method](https://github.com/CoryG89/docsync) which uses javascript after the page is loaded to manipulate relative links. This allows for vanilla style links.