# What does it take to make vanilla relative markdown links work in Jekyll

Tags: hyperlink, markdown, jekyll, kramdown

I'm building a simple Jekyll site.  I've got a collection of markdown files I've already written. When I write I use MacDown because I get to see the images in the preview as I edit (which is great).

Now that I'm porting them to Jekyll (adding frontmatter and whatnot), I've run into a more that slightly annoying problem with vanilla Jekyll.  All of my pages have their assets stored with them.  That way, in the markdown I can just link an image like so:

`![Image about git](git.jpg)`

I opted to keep this organization within Jekyll because the folders and their contents are copied over to `_site` on build as is (I'm not using the `_posts` directory for these pages).  However, the markdown renderer seems to dislike these kinds of links.  According to [everything](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/1325) [I've](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27879849/how-do-i-get-vanilla-markdown-style-relative-links-to-work-with-vanilla-jekyll-a) [read](https://ilovesymposia.com/2015/01/04/some-things-i-learned-while-building-a-site-on-github-pages/), Jekyll doesn't bother translating the markdown for links like this.

My **question** is: what combination of Jekyll and Kramdown plugins/tricks/hacks do I have to use to make these links work?

I'd really love to be able to edit in MacDown (or any side-by-side) editor and see my changes before publishing without just hoping the ugly liquid {{ garbage }} will render correctly when I'm done writing.  I'd also love for my site not to grow a cancerous and unnecessary `img/` folder as I add more content.

EDIT:

Although my question is now answered, I was not actually asking a "what plugin do I need to download" question.  My initial guess was that I'd have to extend the markdown parser myself with my own plugin, which is a programming question.

Comment: As it turns out, the specific issue I was seeing was not with the markdown not being parsed, but with my mixing of HTML and markdown in a way that the markdown parser doesn't like. I'm still fine with this answer as I'm sure I would have run in to this problem again if I added posts in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a plugin that will allow you to do exactly what you're asking (`![Image about git](git.jpg)`). Although because it is a plugin you can't use it on GitHub pages.

It is called [jekyll-postfiles plugin](https://github.com/nhoizey/jekyll-postfiles) by Nicolas Hoizey. He wrote an [article explaining how it works](https://nhoizey.github.io/jekyll-postfiles/) that might also be helpful.

Comment: Man, my Google Fu is clearly in need of training.  I'm not planning on using GitHub pages, so plugins are fine.  I only mentioned vanilla because that's the state I'm in now.  I'm glad this question and answer are here, though, because now there's more links to this plugin for future searchers.